# How do I go about shortening or change this code?

Tags: mysql

Was wondering if it is possible to change the length of this code without changing how the variable functions, its long and might be confusing for others to understand.

```
  $lch = "SELECT worth FROM credit 
     INNER JOIN rawdate ON credit.card_id=_rawdate.card_id 
     WHERE credit.card_id= 
       (SELECT card_id FROM rawdate 
         ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
       )";
```

The database table names are:

> credit: id, card_id, value
>
> rawdate: id, card_id

Comment: Is the inner join to `rawdate` necessary? Like... are you dropping records because of this join? Otherwise, get rid of it. Furthermore, do you get more than one record back from this query? If not, then you could switch this over to a `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY rawdate.id DESC LIMIT 1`. It's tough to help out more without knowing your data.

Comment: This is not a confusing query. It's pretty short and simple. Just like JNevill said, you could write `SELECT worth FROM credit c where card_id = (select card_id from rawdate order by id desc limit 1)`

Comment: Just a note of clarification, it looks like the code says the credit table contains a "worth" column but the database table description says it contains a "value" column instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, this SQL query should produce the same results:

```
select worth 
from credit 
    inner join rawdate on credit.card_id = rawdate.card_id
order by rawdate.id desc
limit 1
```

Essentially, if you're just getting the first rawdate row by ID and using its corresponding card_id to get the worth field from the corresponding credit row with the same card_id, then just ordering the results of the joined table by the rawdate ID and grabbing the first row's worth field should produce the same results.

Please let me know if you require any additional information or assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT worth 
FROM credit 
INNER JOIN rawdate 
ON credit.card_id= rawdate.card_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id FROM rawdate) r_max
ON r_max.id = rawdate.id
```